# Set the Default Value of a Power Apps Dropdown

Tags: powerapps

I have a dialog box in Power Apps that contains a dropdown control.

I have the Default property in the dropdown control set to "6:30"

A person can change the time in the dropdown from "6:30" to another time. For example "7:00" and press the save button.

I would like the default value of the dropdown control to be set back to "6:30" when the person closes the dialog box.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the OnSelect property of your close button of the dialog box by adding :

```
;Reset(TextInput1)
```

You should replace the "TextInput1" by the name of your textinput.